# Importar biblioteca HelloCharts para o Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Minha questão é a seguinte. Estou tentando importar uma biblioteca para poder programar gráficos (gráficos de linha, barra etc) em app.

Estou utilizando como base o site: https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

Baixei a biblioteca, copiei a pasta toda para a pasta "gradle" do Android Studio, coloquei o código como solicitado para importar, mas está dando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, estou colocando o código de forma certa? Os aquivos, copiei para a pasta certa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a atenção!